# How to deploy Gtk+ app on Mac?

Tags: macos, gtk, dylib, .app, jhbuild

Is there a more or less official way for Gtk+ applications to create regular OS X .app with all needed resources and libraries, placed in correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much everyone does their own thing. Check out the outdated (read: not really maintained) bockbuild, as well as the build scripts that gedit uses for building .dmg.

https://github.com/mono/bockbuild
https://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree/osx

This is something I'd love to see migrated to a configure/automake addition with dmg targets.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to deploy a GTK based app on macOS:

[How to deploy GTK based app on Mac OS X?](https://datatable.online/en/blog/004-how-to-deploy-gtk-app-on-mac.html)

You should read it.